# Javascript Row Addition Results In Javascript Calendar Form Element Not To Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has multiple columns in and when a button is pressed it adds another row using javascript.  Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

        function displayResult()
        {
        var table=document.getElementById("expensesTable");
        var row=table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML="<input size='10' id='datepick' name='from[]' style='padding:2px;'/>";
        cell2.innerHTML="<select name='billable[]'><option value='No'>No</option><option value='Yes'>Yes</option></select>";
        }

</script>
```

The row is added when the button is pressed triggered by:

```
onclick='displayResult()'
```

On the javascript row addition, there is a calendar that is also run using javascript.  This is the form field:

```
<input size='10' id='datepick' name='from[]' style='padding:2px;'/>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        new datepickr('datepick', {
            'dateFormat': 'Y-m-d'
        })
</script>
```

This is fine on the first row.  However, when I add further rows it doesn't work.  I know the reason it doesn't work as it's adding the form item with the id datepick which is the same as the one before.  If I were to call it datepick2 and have the javascript like the above with datepick2 in, then it would work.  I just don't know how to increment the id and the javascript for it to work on multiple lines.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would count the number of rows and use that as the id suffix:

JS row counter:

```
var nRows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
```

JQuery row counter:

```
var nRows = $('#expensesTable').children().length;
```

Then modify the id accordingly:

```
cell1.innerHTML="<input size='10' id='datepick"+nRows +"' name='from[]' style='padding:2px;'/>";
```